# Is this a Schrader valve?

Tags: valves, schrader

Is it possible to determine from these 2 photos, whether this valve is a Schrader valve (i.e. the type of valve that is also found on automobile tyres) ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  To get a more definitive answer it would be better to post a new picture without the dust cap on the tube.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a Schrader valve (AV).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a schrader valve, although it would be easier to tell with the valve cover removed.  It appears to be a rare type with threads going all the way up the valve stem to allow a  retaining nut to be used.

Comment: This is normal on Schwalbe tubes, nothing rare.

Comment: This might be normal in the case of schwalbe tubes, but in general it's rare compared to what you might see on the majority of tubes.

Comment: What do you call a "majority"? Schwalbe tubes are extremely common as stock tubes on new bikes. Easily recognized by the clear caps.

Comment: @VladimirF I guess your experience might be different then mine. Perhaps you live in a different part of the world.  Most bikes I see in bike shops use Presta Valves, and I've only seen Schrader valves on department store bikes or on lower end hybrids or cruiser bikes, which in general cut corners by using cheap tires and tubes. I've never seen these in person in my life. I'm not denying they exist, or that in some places they aren't more common. I've never seen dunlop valves either, but they do exist in certain parts of the world.

Comment: Concur - its a schrader valve.  The valve does look like a schwalbe design, with a fully threaded valve stem and a locknut more like a presta, which is pretty-much unique to Schwalbe inner tubes.  They work just like normal schrader tubes.